# Call a function from another function in PHP

Tags: php

I am struggling to implement a php code with the following structure:

```
public function hookActionValidateOrder($params)
{
     $invoice = new Address((int)$order->id_address_invoice);
     $myStreet = $invoice->address1;
     $myCity = $invoice->city;
     $myPostcode = $invoice->postcode;

     // ... SOME IRRELEVANT CODE HERE ...

     $Tid = send($myStreet, $myCity, $myPostcode); /* Calling function send($a, $b, $c) */
}

public function send($a, $b, $c)    /* function send($a, $b, $c) */
{
     // ... CODE TO DO SOMETHING USING VARIABLES $a, $b, $c ...
}
```

The problem is, this code doesn´t seem to work. 
When I put it into a code validator, it says: *"Function 'send()' does not exists"*. Tell me please Why is that so and how do I fix that?

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: are these two functions encapsulated in a class ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using a class, then you can use `$this` for calling the function:

```
class Test {

    public function say($a) {
        return $a ;

    } 

    public function tell() {
        $c = "Hello World" ;
        $a = $this->say($c) ;
        return $a ;
    }
} 

$b= new Test() ;    
echo $b->tell() ;
```

If you are using a normal function, then use closure:

```
function tell(){
   $a = "Hello" ;
   return function($b) use ($a){
      return $a." ".$b ;
   } ;  
}

$s = tell() ;
echo $s("World") ;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you trying to use a Function or any code from the original page 
in a **secondary page** without including it , then usually it show you this Error

> (.... ' string name , function Name ,.......etc ')  **does not exists**

The solution is to **include** it first in your secondary page and use :

```
include("yourpage.php");
```

**if not** then 
 see "@Gulshan" Comment about **"extends" classes**.
it causes the same problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class test 
{
public function hookActionValidateOrder($params)
    {
         $invoice = new Address((int)$order->id_address_invoice);
         $myStreet = $invoice->address1;
         $myCity = $invoice->city;
         $myPostcode = $invoice->postcode;

         // ... SOME IRRELEVANT CODE HERE ...

         $Tid = send($myStreet, $myCity, $myPostcode); /* Calling function send($a, $b, $c) */
    }
  }
class test1 extends test
{
    public function send($a, $b, $c)    /* function send($a, $b, $c) */
    {
         // ... CODE TO DO SOMETHING USING VARIABLES $a, $b, $c ...
    }
}
```

You can solve this with extends one class to another class .

Comment: it is extends not extands

Comment: sorry my mistake..i just updated. thanks for your suggestion :)